# Tcp Port connection shows incompatible value

Tags: c#, tcp, port, tcpclient, tcplistener

Consider the following code:

```
 void Connect(IPAddress address, int port)
{
  TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(address, port);
  listener.Start();
  TcpClient client= new TcpClient();
  //The following line would actually block the caller, but ignore this fact ATM.
  var conn= listener.AcceptTcpClient();
  client.Connect(address,port);  

  var address = ((IPEndPoint)conn.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
  var port = ((IPEndPoint)conn.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port;
}
```

The port number specified by the client does not correspond with the port number which I am able to obtain from the connection. The documentation for this property is pretty vague, and I could not find any similar question here or on MSDN. Does any one have an idea as to why this happens?

Help would be much appreciated.
Eyal.

Comment: You are never going to hit `client.Connect`

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem - please note my comment regarding blocking - I want the example to be as simple as possible. which is why I ignore blocking. the actual implementation takes care of this. Thanks though!

Comment: What comment regarding blocking? You can't accept a connection before the client connects. You have those two lines in the wrong order. This code does not behave as described.

Comment: Actually, you are incorrect, you can accept connections, which blocks until a connection is accepted.. You can not however, connect if the server is not accepting. The comment which I refer to is the only comment within the code block.. @EJP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TCP connection has an independent `(IP, port)` pair for both sides. You are connecting *to* `(address, port)` but you are connecting *from* something else. The from IP and port are chosen automatically by the OS to be appropriate values.

Comment: I suspected as much. is there a way to obtain the information which I would want to see? that the connection is attempted on the port specified by the client?

Comment: What port do you need to know? The remote port? Your code works as is.  LINQPad: var client= new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
 client.Connect("google.com", 80);  

  var address = ((System.Net.IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
  var port = ((System.Net.IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port;
  address.Dump();
  port.Dump();

Comment: suppose that I connect to the server at port 13000, I would like to see that number in the TcpListener returned values. Is that possible?

Comment: Certainly not in the listener but in the client. The listener is not connected. I assume you meant client?

Comment: Anyway, you can ask any TcpListener and get this information. The code you have should work and I also posted executable code that you can run like that. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Actually, I meant the listener, the code which I have does not suffice.. Thank you, in any case, you have answered my question.